# Superconductor-insulator transition at finite temperatures

Tags: research-level, superconductivity, phase-transition, insulators, disorder

I know that it is possible to have a phase transition at $T=0$ between a superconductor and an insulator. The mechanism is not the "usual" QPT as the system is not translationally invariant: the transition is driven by (quenched) disorder so that strong disorder -> insulator, weak disorder -> superconductor.

The question is: is the SI transition possible also at a finite temperature?

In this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1006.5767 after Eq. (3) and later after Eq. (18) they talk about a finite $T$ transition. However, in other papers such as this one https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.03017 they state in the intro that: "At a finite (but sufficiently low) temperature the insulating and superconducting phases of the film are separated by a metallic state."

So what's the deal here?

Comment: For anyone who's interested, I found a paper where they discuss finite T insulators https://www.nature.com/articles/srep13503.